# Share screen from macOS Monterey

Tags: monterey

I was waiting for FaceTime upgrades on macOS Monterey & iOS 15.1.
On iOS 15.1 I can share the screens, but I do not see the option on macOS Monterey, is there any settings which needs to be configured ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePlay for macOS is marked "Coming later this fall." on the feature list.

https://www.apple.com/macos/monterey/features/

Comment: Never saw that detailed list earlier, I was looking around every where else.